# Save site as a template s not working in a new environment - sp 2013 on-prem publishing site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, save-as-template

I have created a wsp from publishing site [rootweb] and save this as a template `http://srvr1:28516/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx` - say **mydmswebsite** & **mydmswebsite.template** file  **without**  including content .

Now  its downloaded int my d driev safely and i have uploaded into another environment thats having the same configurations as original one.
But after uploading the wsp file into the solutions gallery of this new environment & activating the feature, am not able to see the custom site template when i tried to create a subsite.

what am i missing ? any steps / any features i need to add/ activate?